# Can the T-1000 take the form of an animal?

Tags: terminator-2-judgment-day, the-terminator-series

The T-1000 can obviously take the form of humans as well as a wide range of weapons and objects.

**Can it mimic animal forms?**

Comment: Don't see why not...are you asking if it *has*?

Comment: The T-100**1** (Catherine Weaver from TSCC) used part of its body to mimic an eel. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1ymZzOd_jk&feature=youtu.be&t=1m3s

Comment: The TX:A was able to mimic a pack of dogs or a clowder of cats; http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-XA

Comment: In T2:JD, T-800 remarked "This new model can take the shape of ANYTHING it touches". So, it turned into different people after touching their bodies, their shoes. It turned into a freaking chequered floor. Don't see why Skynet wouldn't have programmed it to become a friendly big dog (if size was a constraint).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unknown, but probably yes.

The base-model T-1000 appears in a host of properties (The [T2 film](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(film)) and its [film-novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(Frakes_novel)) & [film graphic novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(comics)), [Terminator Genisys](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_Genisys), the [T2 3-D: Battle Across Timestage show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wM0EZTwE9fM), [two](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_-_Cybernetic_Dawn) [comics](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_-_Nuclear_Twilight) and several licensed novels)

**None of these properties contain an instances of the T-1000 mimicking an animal, or anything other than a human or an inanimate object.**

That being said, as long as the size of the animal was consistent with the size of the T-1000 (say a big dog, or a crocodile), then there's no reason to assume that it *wouldn't* be able to convincingly replicate them. As the [T-800 says](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/t2.txt),

> **JOHN:** *I need a minute here, okay?  You're telling me it can imitate anything it touches?*
>
> **TERMINATOR:** ***Anything*** it samples by physical contact.

Answer (score -2):

No. The T1000 either can't turn into a dog or it is too stupid to.

The timeline in T2:JD is

- T1000 touches Max the dog
- T1000 turns into a blob to pour itself thru a hole in the elevator roof
- T1000 wants to run as fast as possible to catch up to a car
- T1000 does not assume dog form which would enable it to run faster (less air resistance, greater percent of body mass available for locomotion)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You seem to be offering two conflicting answers here though: either 1) No, it can't, or 2) Yes it can, but was too "stupid" to do so in one specific instance. Also, the scene where the T-1000 stabs Max the dog isn't included in the theatrical cut, which means it isn't canon to that cut. So your answer is only relevant to the extended versions of the film, such as the Special Edition.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This answer presumes that the T-1000 has the same musculoskeletal trade-offs as an actual flesh and bone being, which isn't obvious, especially since it can run as fast as it can on two legs.  (And note that bipedal locomotion is more efficient than quadrupedal, which may offset the potential aerodynamic advantages.)  Do you have any evidence it would be faster running as a dog?  (It's also possible the T-1000 decided that having hands was an advantage.)

Comment: Furthermore, the T-800 noted that the T-1000 could only imitate things of "equal size". Max the dog was significantly smaller than Robert Patrick, so that alone would explain why it couldn't imitate Max, without precluding the possibility that it could imitate larger animals.

Comment: The fact that it doesn't doesn't mean that it *can't*, it only demonstrates that it doesn't.